# wpf Datagrid :Validation error not cleared

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a datagrid with a column namely ProductName ,when this cell text change I populate a listview with some Products by filtering using the cell value ,hence the user can select an item from the listview and the selected product is mapped to the cell.I use IDataErrorInfo to validate the selected Product agianst my database table.But my problem is currently I set the UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, when the user select a product which is a valid product from the listview ,still the datagrid shows the validation error .## Heading ##
My xaml is:

```
 <my:DataGrid Name="dgReceiveInventory"  ItemsSource="{Binding}"   SelectionUnit="Cell"   AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="12,84,10,52"  BeginningEdit="dgReceiveInventory_BeginningEdit">
        <my:DataGrid.RowValidationRules>
            <local:RowDataInfoValidationRule ValidationStep="UpdatedValue" />
        </my:DataGrid.RowValidationRules>
        <my:DataGrid.Columns>

            <!--0-Product Column-->
            <my:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Product Name" Width="200">
                <my:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ProductName}"  ></TextBlock>
                        <!--<TextBlock >
                          <TextBlock.Text>
                            <Binding Path="ProductName" >

                               </Binding>
                            </TextBlock.Text>
                        </TextBlock>-->
                    </DataTemplate>
                </my:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <my:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox x:Name="txtbxProduct"  Text="{Binding Path=ProductName,Mode=TwoWay,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxInError}"  TextChanged="txtbxProduct_TextChanged" PreviewKeyDown="txtbxProduct_PreviewKeyDown" >
                                    </TextBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </my:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </my:DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </my:DataGrid.Columns>
    </my:DataGrid>
```

```
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Product_Name}" Header="Product" Width="200" />

            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

My object  is:

```
 class clsProducts : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo
{
    private string _ProductName;


    #region Property Getters and Setters

    public string ProductName
    {
        get { return _ProductName; }
        set
        {
            _ProductName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ProductName");
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region IDataErrorInfo Members

    public string Error
    {
        get
        {
            StringBuilder error = new StringBuilder();

            // iterate over all of the properties
            // of this object - aggregating any validation errors
            PropertyDescriptorCollection props = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this);
            foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in props)
            {
                string propertyError = this[prop.Name];
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyError))
                {
                    error.Append((error.Length != 0 ? ", " : "") + propertyError);
                }
            }

            return error.ToString();
        }
    }

    public string this[string name]
    {
        get
        {
            string result = null;

            if (name == "ProductName")
            {
                int count = Global.ItemExist(this._ProductName);
                if (count == 0)
                {
                    result = "Invalid Product";

                }
            }



            return result;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    // Declare the event
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    //// Create the OnPropertyChanged method to raise the event
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

My listview event which maps the databack to the datagrid :

```
 private void lstvwProduct_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (lstvwProduct.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            int index = DataGridHelper.GetRowIndexOfSelectedCell(dgReceiveInventory);
            if (index == -1 || index == dgReceiveInventory.Items.Count - 1)
                return;
            DataRowView drow = (DataRowView)lstvwProduct.SelectedItem;

            lsItems[index].ProductName = drow.Row["Product_Name"].ToString();

            lstvwProduct.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }
```